# Visual Studio 2017 "Enable Edit and Continue" option checked locks code files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I wanted to use the feature "Edit and Continue" for Visual Studio debugging in Visual Studio 2017 Professional Version 15.9.6 (Problem is present for quite some time, just tackled it down now).
When I check the option for "Enable Edit and Continue" in

```
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
```

and start a Debug-Run afterwards, all .cs files are locked [ReadOnly], even if I hit a breakpoint. (I assume the same for other code files).

[See Screenshot of locked simple console application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPjby.jpg)

I also checked the settings.vssetttings file, the option is really "enabled" / set to 1:

```
<PropertyValue name="ENCEnable">1</PropertyValue>
```

So the question is, how else can I enable "Edit and Continue" or what is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at this issue I finally found out that this is most likely a bug in Visual Studio or caused by some Extension.

If you uncheck the option, it works as expected, the [file is not locked anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgzVn.jpg). 
The property is set to 0, so it is inversed logic somewhere in the program.
You can still check all boxes for native support and the options are still set in the vssettings file. 
Hopefully this helps other people who face the problem.

I also opened an [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/462397/enable-edit-and-continue-option-is-logically-inver.html) at VS dev-community.